# :hover doesn't work in LESS

Tags: hover, styles, less, magento2

How to make :hover work in less?

I need to change a button bg-color on hover and I wrote the following code:

```
  .actions-toolbar {
    .primary {
      display: inline-block;
      button{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        &:hover {
          background-color: #df2423;

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure your html structure is correct? just did a simple codepen with your less and the hover seems to work correctly: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQzRLR Are there no other overriding styles perhaps with more specificity?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the resulting CSS and if that makes sense compared to your HTML structure.

Resulting CSS for your Hover-Style will look like this:

```
.actions-toolbar .primary button:hover { background-color: #df2423; }
```

One thing I always recommend when writing LESS or Sass or equivalent preprocessor languages: (very) careful with the nesting, it can cause irritiation and problems (very) often!